# replacement of the members of a list to produce all possible permutations

Tags: python, permutation

In a list

```
['x', 'x', 'x..', 'x']
```

I wish to replace each `x` in the list (by reading the list into a string) with `.` and `-` in all possible permutations. Thus the output could be

```
['. . ... .'],
['- - -.. -'],
['. - -.. .']
```

and all similar permutations. I have tried the below script but I was able to get just two patterns as output.

```
def fun(inputStringList):
    message_received = inputStringList
    message_received = ' '.join(inputStringList)
    for i in range(len(message_received)):
        x = 'x'
        y = '.'
    message = message_received.replace(x, y)
    message1 = message.split(",")
    print message1
    for i in range(len(message_received)):
        x = 'x'
        y = '-'
    message = message_received.replace(x, y)
    message2 = message.split(",")
    print message2

def funTest():
    test = ['x', 'x', 'x..', 'x']
    print fun(test)
funTest()
```

Output:

```
['. . ... .']
['- - -.. -']
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the *product* of (*number of `x` characters*) `.` and `-` repeated, so `product('.-', number=number_of_x_characters)`.

I'd use `str.format()` to make it easy to interpolate the generated `.` and `-` combinations:

```
from itertools import product

def fun(inputStringList):
    count = sum(s.count('x') for s in inputStringList)
    template = ' '.join(inputStringList).replace('x', '{}')
    for replacements in product('.-', repeat=count):
        yield template.format(*replacements)
```

This is a generator, loop over it:

```
>>> test = ['x', 'x', 'x..', 'x']
>>> for result in fun(test):
...     print(result)
...
. . ... .
. . ... -
. . -.. .
. . -.. -
. - ... .
. - ... -
. - -.. .
. - -.. -
- . ... .
- . ... -
- . -.. .
- . -.. -
- - ... .
- - ... -
- - -.. .
- - -.. -
```